# При нажатии на TextField не выскакивает клавиатура

Tags: objective-c, xcode

При создании TextField через Storyboard перестала вылетать клавиатура при begin editing, подскажите, как это исправить?

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее, в чём состоит проблема.

Comment: При создании TextField через Storyboard перестала вылетать клавиатура при begin editing, подскажите, как это исправить?

Comment: Скиньте пример кода.

Comment: клавиатура не появляется на симуляторе?

Comment: Да, все верно, мне сказали что возможно в симуляторе проблема. Может такое быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убедитесь, что ваш `TextField` определён как `FirstResponder`. Это можно сделать, например, в методе `ViewDidAppear`:

```
 [textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, возможно. Вы просто убрали её появление на симуляторе. Чтобы спрятать, или показать её - необходимо использовать комбинацию клавиш `cmd+shift+k`.